Selenium unable to click on element
I am working on a web scraping project using Selenium in Python and am encountering an issue while interacting with the Lufthansa homepage. My goal is to click a specific element (the Departure field) after accepting cookies. While accepting the cookies works fine, attempting to click the Departure field results in a TimeoutException.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.lufthansa.com/de/de/homepage")

time.sleep(2)

accept_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'cm-acceptAll'))
)
accept_button.click()

time.sleep(5)

departure_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dcep-tab-control-overlay4-checkIn-toggle"]/div/a/i[2]'))
)
departure_field.click()

time.sleep(5) 
driver.quit()


I've also tried using JavaScript execution to click the Departure field, but this did not resolve the issue either:
departure_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dcep-tab-control-overlay4-checkIn-toggle"]/div/a/i[2]'))
)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", departure_field)


The XPath seems correct as it highlights the intended element in the browser's inspector. However, the problem persists.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue or what I might be overlooking? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

It's due to the website detecting selenium bot controlling the browser. Website is not allowing selenium to perform actions. Few references, how to avoid bot detection on websites using selenium python, How to avoid a bot detection and scrape a website using python?
